# How to delete the rows whose column 2 and column 3 matches with some previous using awk?

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file with 4 columns:

```
ifile.txt
3  5  2  2
1  4  2  1
4  5  7  2 
5  5  7  1 
0  0  1  1
3  5  7  3
5  4  2  2
```

I would like to delete the rows whose column 2 & 3 values are same with some previous. for instance, row 2 & 7 have same values in column 2 & 3. Similarly row 3 & 4 & 6 has same values in column 2 & 3. So I want to keep the 2rd row and delete 7th row. Similarly keep 3rd row and delete 4th and 6th row. my output is:

```
ofile.txt
3  5  2  2
1  4  2  1
4  5  7  2
0  0  1  1
```

I tried with this command

```
awk '{a[NR]=$2""$3} a[NR]!=a[NR-1]{print}' ifile.txt > ofile.txt
```

But it is not giving my desire output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk '!(($2,$3) in a); {a[$2,$3]}' ifile
3  5  2  2
1  4  2  1
4  5  7  2
0  0  1  1
```

#### How it works

`awk` reads the input file one line at a time.  Each input line is divided into fields.  In this case, the important fields are the second, denoted `$2`, and the third, denoted `$3`.

- `!(($2,$3) in a)`

  This condition is true if `$2,$3` is not a key in associative array `a`.  Since no action is specified, when this condition is true, the default action is performed which is to print the line.

  In more detail, `($2,$3) in a` is true when `$2,$3` is a key of `a`.  We, however, want the condition to be true in the opposite.  Consequently, we apply awk's negation operator, `!`, to it.
- `a[$2,$3]`

  This adds `$2,$3` as a key of `a`.

Answer (score 4):

Another shorter awk:

```
awk '!seen[$2,$3]++' file

3  5  2  2
1  4  2  1
4  5  7  2
0  0  1  1
```

This awk command uses composite key `$2,$3` and stores them in array `seen`. Value of which is incremented to `1` when a composite key is populated first time.

Answer (score 1):

Use a multidimensional array where column 2 and 3 are the indices. You can then test with `in` whether you already have seen the combination.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html#Multidimensional for details.